# Building error - how to fix missing header file

Tags: compiling, make, imagemagick, cmake

I'm trying to build **[cuneiform](https://launchpad.net/cuneiform-linux)** from source with imageMagick support, but it looks like the debian package missing a header file.
When I'm running `make` it fails at the very end of the process:

```
[100%] Building CXX object cuneiform_src/cli/CMakeFiles/cuneiform-cli.dir/cuneiform-cli.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick-6/Magick++/Include.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/ImageMagick-6/Magick++.h:9,
                 from /tmp/cuneiform-linux-1.1.0/cuneiform_src/cli/cuneiform-cli.cpp:156:
/usr/include/ImageMagick-6/magick/magick-config.h:21:38: fatal error: magick/magick-baseconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #include "magick/magick-baseconfig.h"
                                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

By searching for the header, it turns out it can be found in a different ImageMagick directory:

```
$ find /usr/include/ -name "*baseconfig*"
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6/magick/magick-baseconfig.h7
```

Dumb soft linking the missing file didn't solved the problem.

How can I get the compiler use the other include directory?

Comment: What does `pkg-config --cflags ImageMagick` print on your system? On my Jessie systems, the appropriate `-I` flags are included already.

Comment: `-fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6`

Answer (score 3):

Cuneiform’s `CMakeLists.txt` doesn’t include libraries’ arch-specific include path. To fix this for ImageMagick, change line 40 of `cuneiform_src/CMakeLists.txt` from

```
include_directories(${ImageMagick_Magick++_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

to

```
include_directories(${ImageMagick_Magick++_INCLUDE_DIR} ${ImageMagick_Magick++_ARCH_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

CMake’s `pkg-config` integration retrieves the information correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Ref. http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jpakkane/cuneiform-linux/trunk/files

The files in cuneiform_src/ have a time stamp = 2010 or earlier. No wonder the new fancy Debian path isn't found. ( magick/magick-baseconfig.h not found ).

An easy fix : # `mkdir /usr/local/include/magick`

```
# cp /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6/magick/magick-baseconfig.h /usr/local/include/magick/
```

... And the executable `cuneiform` is created.